# Axios post adds extra key to object

Tags: javascript, object, post, axios

I try to post an object with axios. I need it to be in a format like this:

```
var dataObj = {username:"username",password:"password",data1:"data1"};
```

When i POST it with axios and catch in the backend, it adds an extra key to the object like this:

```
{dataObj:{username:"username",password:"password",data1:"data1"}};
```

How can i get rid of this extra field before sending it to backend so it will look like this?

```
{username:"username",password:"password",data1:"data1"}
```

I know i can parse it in the backend but i cant modify the backend cuz its not mine.

This is how my axios post looks like:

```
axios.post('http://192.168.1.1xx:3000/data', {
    dataObj
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: also the object changes dynamically so i cant add the fields one-by-one to the POST body, unless there is a looping function for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
axios.post('http://192.168.1.1xx:3000/data', 
    dataObj
)
```

Instead of :

```
axios.post('http://192.168.1.1xx:3000/data', {
    dataObj
})
```

Remove brackets  ↪ i mean `,dataObj)` instead of `, {dataObj})` ... because "dataObj" is already a literal object.

Comment: it still adds a {data:{... key in the response but i think i can live with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the original question is to use the url encoded format documented in the axios github repository:
 https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

I've tested using '[qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs)' and works as requested.

```
const qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
```