# Axios POST request passing all params as one body key

Tags: node.js, post, axios

I have a simple Axios POST request:

```
 const data = JSON.stringify({
    to: receiver,
    from: sender,
    body: message
  });

  axios.post(window.location.origin + '/sms/outgoing', data)
```

My issue is that my api reads the request body as this:

```
{ '{"to":"12345","from":"54321","body":"message"}': '' }
```

when I want it to be this:

```
{"to":"12345","from":"54321","body":"message"}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens when you don't stringify your data?

Comment: @helllomatt the body is blank

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how did you resolve this?

Comment: This is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974850/axios-post-adds-extra-key-to-object/56142669#56142669), and a proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142669/4544238) just posted there.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify method is not need..

```
  const data = {
      to: receiver,
      from: sender,
      body: message
    };

  axios.post(window.location.origin + '/sms/outgoing', data)
```

but you need JSON.stringify method to follow this backend api call

```
  app.route(window.location.origin + '/sms/outgoing',(req,res)=>{
    let data = JSON.parse(req.body)
    console.log(data) //get {"to":"12345","from":"54321","body":"message"}
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to parse the JSON object from a JSON string, just use the `JSON.parse` function

```
const object = JSON.parse({
  someJSONString: true,
})
```

Comment: I'm not using ajax, and `axios.setRequestHeader` is not a function.